# In R, according to current statistic values, how to know the raw data like and apply regression analysis

Tags: r, regression

I have two variables x,y ,currently know the 'mean value \sd value\ ssx\ssy':

1. is there any way to know actual x/y specific values ?
2. according to current statistic value, is it ok to have regression analysis for y~ x ?

[image]

Comment: In addition to @StupidWolf, you can use back tracing to figure out a 'possible' solution for x and y which those metrics. However as there are arguably more than one solution, you will never know what the original observation was and thus you cannot do a linear regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve for the original values of either $X$ or $Y$, given the mean and standard deviation, you have two equations and sixteen unknowns. Algebra tells you that there are multiple solutions. The answer to question #1 is **NO**.

However, even if you could solve for the original values, you would be missing critical information for the regression: how the values are paired. Let's do an example.

$$
X = (1, 2, 3, 4),
Y = (1, 3, 2, 4)\\
\text{vs}\\
X = (1, 2, 3, 4),
Y = (4,1,3,2)\\
$$

Both rows feature the same summary statistics (mean and standard deviation) of $X$ and $Y$. However, the regression equations would be different, since the pairing of values is different. For the first data set, the pairing would be $((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 4))$, while the second gives $((1, 4), (2,1), (3, 3), (4,2))$.